# Showing/hiding elements ajax Drupal

Tags: ajax, drupal-7

I got a problem with showing elements in my page. Depending on choose of the role-radio i need to show|hide select-elements. So im hidin` an element like this:

```
$form['field_test_field']['#access'] = 0;
```

But when the state changes i aint able to bring it back by binding 1. So thats my snippet:

```
function seven_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['account']['roles']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'seven_dynamic_form_ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'replace_droplist',
        'event' => 'change',
    );

    $form['field_test_field']['#prefix'] = '<div id="replace_droplist">';
    $form['field_test_field']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    $form['account']['roles']['#type'] = 'radios';

    $checkedRole = isset($form_state['values']['roles'])
        ? $form_state['values']['roles'] : 0;

    if ($checkedRole == 0) {
        $form['field_test_field']['#access'] = 1;
    } elseif ($checkedRole == 4) {
        $form['field_test_field']['#access'] = 0;
    } elseif ($checkedRole == 3) {
        $form['field_test_field']['#access'] = 1;
    }
};

function seven_dynamic_form_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['field_test_field'];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: ive changed #access attribute to #disabled, so then it works im able to turn on/off component using radio button but i havent got why #access has differrent behaviour....

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
$form['enter_amt'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Enter Billable Amount'),
  );
  $form['billable_ctc'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Billable CTC'),
    '#maxlength' => '15',
    '#field_prefix' => t('Rs.'),
    '#states' => array('invisible' => array(':input[name="enter_amt"]' =>         array('checked' => TRUE), ), ),
  );
  $form['billing_rate'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Billing rate'),
    '#maxlength' => '7',
    '#field_suffix' => '%',
    '#size' => 3,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('auto-width')),
    '#states' => array('invisible' => array(':input[name="enter_amt"]' => array('checked' => TRUE), ), ),
  );
</code>
```

This code worked for me to hide and show particular form element based on clicking of the checkbox.